# RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806 MiB/s

Tags: xcode, github, terminal, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I am trying to install my cocoa pods.
After doing everything and installing it i got the error :

```
[!] Unable to add a source with url git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git named master-1
```

And to fix that error I tried:

```
 cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
 git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

Then I get this error which I don't know how to deal with:

```
remote: Counting objects: 854549, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3453/3453), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806 MiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 4):

The `git clone` is indeed what [issue 4293](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293#issuecomment-144384681) recommends.

But if the clone fails with a "`RPC failed; result=56`" error message, check your git buffer:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 2M
```

Then try again your `git clone`.

If not, investigate with:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
```

Finally, if https does not want to cooperate, try the ssh url:

```
cd  ~/.cocoapods/repos 
git clone git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git
```

Comment: i did this and i still get this error: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @alibabaei12 this time, it is an ssh issue: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/ and https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/. Make sure to generate an ssh key *without* passphrase, ni order to not have to deal (at least for testing purposes) with ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously try 3 times *pod setup* first and second time it fails. third time it works. Even if the third time fails run again it and continuously open a webpage or stream online videos, this will works. i have tested two times, one in 10.12sieraa

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. In my case I resolved it by changing to http.

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

Comment: All this does is clone to a directory named "master" - how does this solve the OP's issue?